# How to delete the backref link in \fullcite when to invoke the caspervector-ay style in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, fullcite

First an MWE and its output with XeLaTeX are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, utf8, style=caspervector-ay,
maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=999, backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{jensen1916,
    author= {A. Jensen and B. Bonus and N. Loretan and D. Yong},
    title = {Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania},
    journal = {Maal og Minne},
    year = {1916},
    volume={26},
    number = {1},
    pages= {60--89}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\fullcite{jensen1916}

\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the `\fullcite` produces the backref link when to invoke the `caspervector-ay` style in `biblatex`. As you may know, this won't happen when to invoke the `autheryear-icomp` style or others. So my question is: *How to delete the backref link in `\fullcite` when to invoke the `caspervector-ay` style in `biblatex`?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard styles use the bibmacro `pageref` to print the back references. This bibmacro is specifically disabled in `\AtUsedriver` (so will not be used with `\fullcite`). `biblatex-caspervector` uses its own bibmacro `addendum+pageref` to print the back references and does not disable its use in `\AtUsedriver`.

The simplest solution is probably to delete the `pageref` list in `\AtUsedriver`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, utf8, style=caspervector-ay,
maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=999, backref=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtUsedriver{\clearlist{pageref}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation without back ref, reference list entry with back ref.]

Comment: @M.Logic you can find the name in the biblatex documentation.

Comment: @M.Logic make an educated guess by looking at the begin of the names.

Comment: Well, Moritz Wemheuer. Then how to pronounce "Wemheuer"? Could you give the IPA for it?